# MacBinary converter for iOS and Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I looking for code to convert a MacBinaryIII encode file on iOS and Mac OS X. The only two I could find are Christopher Evans [MacBinaryIII](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/zip/zip-6/unzip/unzip/macos/source/macbin3.h) and Sean Hummels [MacBinaryIII OSAX 1.0.1](http://www.oocities.org/hummelsean/) which both use API that are not available on iOS or the 64-bit Mac OS X Obj-C runtime.

Comment: There's a MacBinary class in [Open Powerplant](http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-powerplant/), but I doubt that it's much more modern code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in an unenviable position, having to resurrect code that old to handle an encoding that, well, isn't used that much if at all in these days. Your task is made somewhat easier by needing only the decoding.

In `MacBinaryIII.c/.h`, do the following:

Get rid of `EncodeMacBinaryFile()`, `EncodeMacBinaryFiles()`, `EncodeMacBinary()`, and `FSpIsMacBinary()`.

Get rid of `SetDesktopComment()` too, and remove its use in `DecodeMacBinaryFiles()` and `DecodeMacBinary()`; if all you want is the converted file, this is superfluous.

While you've greatly simplified things, you need to convert the code so that it works with file paths rather than those `FSSpec` structures that held filenames in Pascal strings with a maximum limit of 31 characters. To that end:

Rename the file with a .m extension rather than .c to handle the Cocoa stuff.

For determining if the file is present, you can use `-[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:]`.

For reading the file, you can use `NSFileHandle` quick and dirty to get the file contents for conversion. You'll get a NSData back, and will need to make a mutable copy of it for converting its contents. For writing out the converted data, you can take advantage of NSMutableData's ability to write out to a file.

And finally, beware of endian issues while performing the byte manipulation. This code was written in the days of 68000 (and descendants) hardware, and PowerPC: big-endian.

I wish I had something that I could just drop in your lap, ready to go, but given this particular task, this is all I can offer.

Good luck!

Comment: Unenviable position, I think that's in my job title ;) Thx.